# How do you solve this given 3 angles and one magnitude only?

Tags: vectors

The two forces shown act on the structural member AB. Determine the magnitude of P such that the resultant of these forces is directed along AB.

Here's an image of the whole problem..

http://tinypic.com/r/34fo65x/8

(Sorry i cant post images since i need 10 reps to do so.. :()

Comment: I hope somebody can help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the linked picture, consider the forces in the diagram below :-
[image]

The resultant is formed by the vector addition of forces $P$ and $5 kN$ and must be in line with the bar (so that it is directed along $AB$).

This forms a parallelogram. We can use the sine rule on the triangle that is half the parallelogram:-
$$\frac{P}{\sin 30}=\frac{5}{\sin 50}\Rightarrow P=0.5\times 5\times\frac{1}{\sin 50}\approx 3.26 kN$$